# Faster AAN algorithm for calculating Discrete Cosine Transform

Tags: performance, c, image

I was implementing the AAN algorithm for computing the 2D Discrete Cosine Transform on an 8*8 array. I perform both the forward and inverse AAN algorithms.

My code is extremely fast compared to the naive DCT algorithm but I feel that my implementation could be faster. How can I improve the performance of my transforms?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifndef M_PI
#    define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif
/*
File: dct.c
Summary: 2D AAN implementation of Discrete Cosine transform
     Code for Forward and Inverse DCT using AAN method
Sources: Forward DCT inspired by // https://unix4lyfe.org/dct-1d/
     Inverse DCT inspired by (Everything you need to know about jpeg Youtube Playlist) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sb8CQ9knDgI&list=PLpsTn9TA_Q8VMDyOPrDKmSJYt1DLgDZU4

Input : float array of 64 elements representing 8 * 8 block
*Note I use a 1-dimensional array to represent 2d data   
*/


//Compute forward dct
void ForwardDCTComponent(float *component)
{
/*Forward DCT constants*/
const float a1 = 0.707;
const float a2 = 0.541;
const float a3 = 0.707;
const float a4 = 1.307;
const float a5 = 0.383;

const float s0 = 0.353553;
const float s1 = 0.254898;
const float s2 = 0.270598;
const float s3 = 0.300672;
const float s4 = s0;
const float s5 = 0.449988;
const float s6 = 0.653281;
const float s7 = 1.281458;
/*Forward DCT constants*/


    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        const float b0 = component[0*8 + i] + component[7*8 + i];
        const float b1 = component[1*8 + i] + component[6*8 + i];
        const float b2 = component[2*8 + i] + component[5*8 + i];
        const float b3 = component[3*8 + i] + component[4*8 + i];
        const float b4 =-component[4*8 + i] + component[3*8 + i];
        const float b5 =-component[5*8 + i] + component[2*8 + i];
        const float b6 =-component[6*8 + i] + component[1*8 + i];
        const float b7 =-component[7*8 + i] + component[0*8 + i];
        
        const float c0 = b0 + b3;
        const float c1 = b1 + b2;
        const float c2 =-b2 + b1;
        const float c3 =-b3 + b0;
        const float c4 =-b4 - b5;
        const float c5 = b5 + b6;
        const float c6 = b6 + b7;
        const float c7 = b7;
        
        const float d0 = c0 + c1;
        const float d1 =-c1 + c0;
        const float d2 = c2 + c3;
        const float d3 = c3;
        const float d4 = c4;
        const float d5 = c5;
        const float d6 = c6;
        const float d7 = c7;
        const float d8 = (d4+d6) * a5;
        
        const float e0 = d0;
        const float e1 = d1;
        const float e2 = d2 * a1;
        const float e3 = d3;
        const float e4 = -d4 * a2 - d8;
        const float e5 = d5 * a3;
        const float e6 = d6 * a4 - d8;
        const float e7 = d7;
        
        const float f0 = e0;
        const float f1 = e1;
        const float f2 = e2 + e3;
        const float f3 = e3 - e2;
        const float f4 = e4;
        const float f5 = e5 + e7;
        const float f6 = e6;
        const float f7 = e7 - e5;
        
        const float g0 = f0;
        const float g1 = f1;
        const float g2 = f2;
        const float g3 = f3;
        const float g4 = f4 + f7;
        const float g5 = f5 + f6;
        const float g6 = -f6 + f5;
        const float g7 = f7 - f4;   
        
        component[0*8 + i] = g0 * s0;
        component[4*8 + i] = g1 * s4;
        component[2*8 + i] = g2 * s2;
        component[6*8 + i] = g3 * s6;
        component[5*8 + i] = g4 * s5;
        component[1*8 + i] = g5 * s1;
        component[7*8 + i] = g6 * s7;
        component[3*8 + i] = g7 * s3;       
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        const float b0 = component[i*8 + 0]  + component[i*8 + 7];
        const float b1 = component[i*8 + 1]  + component[i*8 + 6];
        const float b2 = component[i*8 + 2]  + component[i*8 + 5];
        const float b3 = component[i*8 + 3]  + component[i*8 + 4];
        const float b4 =-component[i*8 + 4]  + component[i*8 + 3];
        const float b5 =-component[i*8 + 5]  + component[i*8 + 2];
        const float b6 =-component[i*8 + 6]  + component[i*8 + 1];
        const float b7 =-component[i*8 + 7]  + component[i*8 + 0] ;
        
        const float c0 = b0 + b3;
        const float c1 = b1 + b2;
        const float c2 =-b2 + b1;
        const float c3 =-b3 + b0;
        const float c4 =-b4 - b5;
        const float c5 = b5 + b6;
        const float c6 = b6 + b7;
        const float c7 = b7;
        
        const float d0 = c0 + c1;
        const float d1 =-c1 + c0;
        const float d2 = c2 + c3;
        const float d3 = c3;
        const float d4 = c4;
        const float d5 = c5;
        const float d6 = c6;
        const float d7 = c7;
        const float d8 = (d4+d6) * a5;
        
        const float e0 = d0;
        const float e1 = d1;
        const float e2 = d2 * a1;
        const float e3 = d3;
        const float e4 = -d4 * a2 - d8;
        const float e5 = d5 * a3;
        const float e6 = d6 * a4 - d8;
        const float e7 = d7;
        
        const float f0 = e0;
        const float f1 = e1;
        const float f2 = e2 + e3;
        const float f3 = e3 - e2;
        const float f4 = e4;
        const float f5 = e5 + e7;
        const float f6 = e6;
        const float f7 = e7 - e5;
        
        const float g0 = f0;
        const float g1 = f1;
        const float g2 = f2;
        const float g3 = f3;
        const float g4 = f4 + f7;
        const float g5 = f5 + f6;
        const float g6 = -f6 + f5;
        const float g7 = f7 - f4;   
        
        component[i*8 + 0] = g0 * s0;
        component[i*8 + 4] = g1 * s4;
        component[i*8 + 2] = g2 * s2;
        component[i*8 + 6] = g3 * s6;
        component[i*8 + 5] = g4 * s5;
        component[i*8 + 1] = g5 * s1;
        component[i*8 + 7] = g6 * s7;
        component[i*8 + 3] = g7 * s3;   
    }
}

void InverseDCTComponent(float *component)
{
const float m0 = 2.0 * cos(1.0/16.0 * 2.0 * M_PI);
const float m1 = 2.0 * cos(2.0/16.0 * 2.0 * M_PI);
const float m3 = 2.0 * cos(2.0/16.0 * 2.0 * M_PI);
const float m5 = 2.0 * cos(3.0/16.0 * 2.0 * M_PI);
const float m2 = m0-m5;
const float m4 = m0+m5;

const float s0 = cos(0.0/16.0 *M_PI)/sqrt(8);
const float s1 = cos(1.0/16.0 *M_PI)/2.0;
const float s2 = cos(2.0/16.0 *M_PI)/2.0;
const float s3 = cos(3.0/16.0 *M_PI)/2.0;
const float s4 = cos(4.0/16.0 *M_PI)/2.0;
const float s5 = cos(5.0/16.0 *M_PI)/2.0;
const float s6 = cos(6.0/16.0 *M_PI)/2.0;
const float s7 = cos(7.0/16.0 *M_PI)/2.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        const float g0 = component[0*8 + i] * s0;
        const float g1 = component[4*8 + i] * s4;
        const float g2 = component[2*8 + i] * s2;
        const float g3 = component[6*8 + i] * s6;
        const float g4 = component[5*8 + i] * s5;
        const float g5 = component[1*8 + i] * s1;
        const float g6 = component[7*8 + i] * s7;
        const float g7 = component[3*8 + i] * s3;
        
        const float f0 = g0;
        const float f1 = g1;
        const float f2 = g2;
        const float f3 = g3;
        const float f4 = g4 - g7;
        const float f5 = g5 + g6;
        const float f6 = g5 - g6;
        const float f7 = g4 + g7;
        
        const float e0 = f0;
        const float e1 = f1;
        const float e2 = f2 - f3;
        const float e3 = f2 + f3;
        const float e4 = f4;
        const float e5 = f5 - f7;
        const float e6 = f6;
        const float e7 = f5 + f7;
        const float e8 = f4 + f6;
        
        const float d0 = e0;
        const float d1 = e1;
        const float d2 = e2 * m1;
        const float d3 = e3;
        const float d4 = e4 * m2;
        const float d5 = e5 * m3;
        const float d6 = e6 * m4;
        const float d7 = e7;
        const float d8 = e8 * m5;
        
        const float c0 = d0 + d1;
        const float c1 = d0 - d1;
        const float c2 = d2 - d3;
        const float c3 = d3;
        const float c4 = d4 + d8;
        const float c5 = d5 + d7;
        const float c6 = d6 - d8;
        const float c7 = d7;
        const float c8 = c5 - c6;
        
        const float b0 = c0 + c3;
        const float b1 = c1 + c2;
        const float b2 = c1 - c2;
        const float b3 = c0 - c3;
        const float b4 = c4 - c8;
        const float b5 = c8;
        const float b6 = c6 - c7;
        const float b7 = c7;
        
        component[0 * 8 + i] = b0 + b7;
        component[1 * 8 + i] = b1 + b6;
        component[2 * 8 + i] = b2 + b5;
        component[3 * 8 + i] = b3 + b4;
        component[4 * 8 + i] = b3 - b4;
        component[5 * 8 + i] = b2 - b5;
        component[6 * 8 + i] = b1 - b6;
        component[7 * 8 + i] = b0 - b7; 
    }
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++)
    {
        const float g0 = component[i*8 + 0] * s0;
        const float g1 = component[i*8 + 4] * s4;
        const float g2 = component[i*8 + 2] * s2;
        const float g3 = component[i*8 + 6] * s6;
        const float g4 = component[i*8 + 5] * s5;
        const float g5 = component[i*8 + 1] * s1;
        const float g6 = component[i*8 + 7] * s7;
        const float g7 = component[i*8 + 3] * s3;
        
        const float f0 = g0;
        const float f1 = g1;
        const float f2 = g2;
        const float f3 = g3;
        const float f4 = g4 - g7;
        const float f5 = g5 + g6;
        const float f6 = g5 - g6;
        const float f7 = g4 + g7;
        
        const float e0 = f0;
        const float e1 = f1;
        const float e2 = f2 - f3;
        const float e3 = f2 + f3;
        const float e4 = f4;
        const float e5 = f5 - f7;
        const float e6 = f6;
        const float e7 = f5 + f7;
        const float e8 = f4 + f6;
        
        const float d0 = e0;
        const float d1 = e1;
        const float d2 = e2 * m1;
        const float d3 = e3;
        const float d4 = e4 * m2;
        const float d5 = e5 * m3;
        const float d6 = e6 * m4;
        const float d7 = e7;
        const float d8 = e8 * m5;
        
        const float c0 = d0 + d1;
        const float c1 = d0 - d1;
        const float c2 = d2 - d3;
        const float c3 = d3;
        const float c4 = d4 + d8;
        const float c5 = d5 + d7;
        const float c6 = d6 - d8;
        const float c7 = d7;
        const float c8 = c5 - c6;
        
        const float b0 = c0 + c3;
        const float b1 = c1 + c2;
        const float b2 = c1 - c2;
        const float b3 = c0 - c3;
        const float b4 = c4 - c8;
        const float b5 = c8;
        const float b6 = c6 - c7;
        const float b7 = c7;
        
        component[i * 8 + 0] = b0 + b7;
        component[i * 8 + 1] = b1 + b6;
        component[i * 8 + 2] = b2 + b5;
        component[i * 8 + 3] = b3 + b4;
        component[i * 8 + 4] = b3 - b4;
        component[i * 8 + 5] = b2 - b5;
        component[i * 8 + 6] = b1 - b6;
        component[i * 8 + 7] = b0 - b7;
    }
}

void Print(float *array, int length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        if(i > 0 && i % 8 == 0)
        {
            putchar('\n');
        }
        printf("%.1f ", array[i]);  
    }
    putchar('\n');
}




int main()
{
    //Create Sample Array 
    float *component = malloc(64 * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        component[i] = 255;
    }
    //Print Sample Array
    Print(component,64);
    
    //Perform forward DCT
    ForwardDCTComponent(component);
    putchar('\n');
    //Print results of forward dct
    Print(component,64);
    
    //Perform inverse DCT
    InverseDCTComponent(component);
    putchar('\n');
    //Print results of inverse dct
    Print(component,64);
    free(component);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What sort of things are in scope for improving the performance? Maybe SIMD? Fixed-point approximations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Performance**

> How can I improve the performance of my transforms?

So far, only some small ideas.

**`float` vs. `double` math**

Do not call run-time `double` functions and constants for `float` math.  A lot of time can be spent up and down converting.

```
// const float s1 = cos(1.0/16.0 * M_PI)/2.0;
define M_PIf 3.14159265f
const float s1 = cosf(1.0f/16.0f * M_PIf)/2.0f;
```

On the other hand, even better to pre-calculate with high precision and then  ...

**Use constants**

Some compilers will form compile time constants values involving constant equations with well known functions at compile time, others  calculate at run-time.  Simple coding the value is fastest.  Some issues apply concerng how many digits to code.  I reccomend at least 9 for `float` and OK to have many more.  Pedantic code would use 17+ in case `float` has same precision as `double`.  Your call.

```
// const float s0 = cos(0.0/16.0 *M_PI)/sqrt(8);
const float s0 = 0.353553391f // cos(0.0/16.0 *M_PI)/sqrt(8);
```

**`static`**

Depending on the compiler, a `const` object may get re-loaded in a function.

`static` will certainly prevent that.

```
// const float s0 = 0.353553391f // cos(0.0/16.0 *M_PI)/sqrt(8);
static const float s0 = 0.353553391f // cos(0.0/16.0 *M_PI)/sqrt(8);
```

**Micro optimization**

Might save a tick or two

```
 //for(int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++)
 //  ...  i*8 ...
 //  ...  i*8 ...
 for(int i = 0 ; i < 64; i+=8)
   ...  i ...
   ...  i ...
```

**Save coding time**

This is a saving of your valuable coding time.

`void Print(float *array, int length)` does not use `length`.  With a well enabled compiler, that would have generated a warning.  Yet since it is there, it implies all warnings were not enabled.

Save time, enable all warnings to guide you to better code.

---

**Correctness**

**Coding `float` vs. `double` constants**

```
// const float s0 = 0.353553;
const float s0 = 0.353553f;
```

See [When does appending an 'f' change the value of a floating constant when assigned to a `float`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/2410359)

**Suspicious values**

For `a1, a2, ...`, why only 3 significant digits constants?  Perhaps `float a1 = 0.707106781f;` is better?

**Assessing**

To judge the correctness of a `float`, avoid using `"%.1f"` as that takes the *floating* out of floating point.  Wee values are all `0.0` and large values have excessive digits.

```
// printf("%.1f ", array[i]);
printf("%.*g ", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, array[i]);
```

---

**Latent Bug**

`float` and `int` are not specified to have the same size.

Avoid sizing errors.  Size to the referenced object, not type.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// float *component = malloc(64 * sizeof(int)); // int ???
float *component = malloc(sizeof *component * 64);
```